# Incorporating additional functions to game

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Good afternoon, everyone. Business student here who is assigned a python game for my current module (where we need to construct a game based on a Jupyter Notebook, matching certain metrics and requirements such, as a scoreboard, that shows the top 5 player's scores as well as complexity level of the game).

I decided on a Tic-Tac-Toe game for 2 players, and was provided the source code by Aprataksh (credits to him, thank you!).

I want to incorporate a coin-flip function to determine which player goes first, as well as changing the Player X and O to the specific player names when they win (it shows Player X and O wins rather than Player Tom or John)

Lastly, **a scoreboard that keeps track of the top 5 players when Jupyter is shut down and restores when it is open. I understand that this is through a .txt and open read function but I can't seem to add it.**

Wish to seek for help or assistance/tips that can be provided for my reference and understanding, thank you!

Below is the attached source code:

```
#Welcome message
print ("Welcome to the game of Tic Tac Toe!")

# Function to print Tic Tac Toe
def print_tic_tac_toe(values):
    print("\n")
    print("\t     |     |")
    print("\t  {}  |  {}  |  {}".format(values[0], values[1], values[2]))
    print('\t_____|_____|_____')

    print("\t     |     |")
    print("\t  {}  |  {}  |  {}".format(values[3], values[4], values[5]))
    print('\t_____|_____|_____')

    print("\t     |     |")

    print("\t  {}  |  {}  |  {}".format(values[6], values[7], values[8]))
    print("\t     |     |")
    print("\n")


# Function to print the score-board
def print_scoreboard(score_board):
    print("\t--------------------------------")
    print("\t              SCOREBOARD       ")
    print("\t--------------------------------")

    players = list(score_board.keys())
    print("\t   ", players[0], "\t    ", score_board[players[0]])
    print("\t   ", players[1], "\t    ", score_board[players[1]])

    print("\t--------------------------------\n")

# Function to check if any player has won
def check_win(player_pos, cur_player):

    # All possible winning combinations
    soln = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]]

    # Loop to check if any winning combination is satisfied
    for x in soln:
        if all(y in player_pos[cur_player] for y in x):

            # Return True if any winning combination satisfies
            return True
    # Return False if no combination is satisfied       
    return False        

# Function to check if the game is drawn
def check_draw(player_pos):
    if len(player_pos['X']) + len(player_pos['O']) == 9:
        return True
    return False        

# Function for a single game of Tic Tac Toe
def single_game(cur_player):

    # Represents the Tic Tac Toe
    values = [' ' for x in range(9)]
    
    # Stores the positions occupied by X and O
    player_pos = {'X':[], 'O':[]}
    
    # Game Loop for a single game of Tic Tac Toe
    while True:
        print_tic_tac_toe(values)
        
        # Try exception block for MOVE input
        try:
            print("Player ", cur_player, " turn. Which box? : ", end="")
            move = int(input()) 
        except ValueError:
            print("Wrong Input!!! Try Again")
            continue

        # Sanity check for MOVE inout
        if move < 1 or move > 9:
            print("Wrong Input!!! Try Again")
            continue

        # Check if the box is not occupied already
        if values[move-1] != ' ':
            print("Place already filled. Try again!!")
            continue

        # Update game information

        # Updating grid status 
        values[move-1] = cur_player

        # Updating player positions
        player_pos[cur_player].append(move)

        # Function call for checking win
        if check_win(player_pos, cur_player):
            print_tic_tac_toe(values)
            print("Player ", cur_player, " has won the game!!")     
            print("\n")
            return cur_player

        # Function call for checking draw game
        if check_draw(player_pos):
            print_tic_tac_toe(values)
            print("Game Drawn")
            print("\n")
            return 'D'

        # Switch player moves
        if cur_player == 'X':
            cur_player = 'O'
        else:
            cur_player = 'X'

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Player 1")
    player1 = input("Please enter your name : ")
    print("\n")

    print("Player 2")
    player2 = input("Please enter your name : ")
    print("\n")
    
    # Stores the player who chooses X and O
    cur_player = player1

    # Stores the choice of players
    player_choice = {'X' : "", 'O' : ""}

    # Stores the options
    options = ['X', 'O']

    # Stores the scoreboard
    score_board = {player1: 0, player2: 0}
    print_scoreboard(score_board)
    
    # Game Loop for a series of Tic Tac Toe
    # The loop runs until the players quit 
    while True:
        
        # Player choice Menu
        print("Turn to choose for", cur_player)
        print("Enter 1 for X")
        print("Enter 2 for O")
        print("Enter 3 to Quit")

        # Try exception for CHOICE input
        try:
            choice = int(input())   
        except ValueError:
            print("Wrong Input!!! Try Again\n")
            continue

        # Conditions for player choice  
        if choice == 1:
            player_choice['X'] = cur_player
            if cur_player == player1:
                player_choice['O'] = player2
            else:
                player_choice['O'] = player1

        elif choice == 2:
            player_choice['O'] = cur_player
            if cur_player == player1:
                player_choice['X'] = player2
            else:
                player_choice['X'] = player1
        
        elif choice == 3:
            print("Final Scores")
            print_scoreboard(score_board)
            print("Thank you for playing! See you again.")            
            break   

        else:
            print("Wrong Choice!!!! Try Again\n")

        # Stores the winner in a single game of Tic Tac Toe
        winner = single_game(options[choice-1])
        
        # Edits the scoreboard according to the winner
        if winner != 'D' :
            player_won = player_choice[winner]
            score_board[player_won] = score_board[player_won] + 1

        print_scoreboard(score_board)
        # Switch player who chooses X or O
        if cur_player == player1:
            cur_player = player2
        else:
            cur_player = player1
```

Comment: What is your question? What challenges have you faced adding the features you describe to the existing code? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's a Q&A site for programmers. You need to ask an actual question, and ["Can anyone help me?" is not an acceptable one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: @Blckknght Hi Blckknight, my apologies if my question seem to categorized under a "please help me", understood that in some context, I'm missing out on the technical questions as well as the challenges faced. I'm struggling to input the coin flip function before the Player Choice Menu, as well as adding on the .txt to save the scoreboard into a text file (more of the question of where should I place it).